# How to generate animations based on the sketches?

Tags: sketching, animate

I recently came across [this video](https://youtu.be/N282bXQYRFc?t=286), where a sketch is generated as a video animation.

I have a good idea of how to sketch in Photoshop, for example, if I have the exact the same sketch with layers in Photoshop or Krita. How do  I generate the animation like the one in the above video?

Which workflow, software, and tools I need to know about?

Comment: Draw sketch erase stuff layer by layer and save as you go along.

Comment: Some applications have these types of screen capture features built in. [**Krita**](https://docs.krita.org/en/reference_manual/dockers/recorder_docker.html) has a built in recording functionality. Here's [a video on that](https://youtu.be/SXPUVtqqSqM?t=54). Just as another example, [iOS app Procreate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTbNbtoGdeg) has something similar.

Comment: Photoshop doesn't have recording... If I were to use PS or anything else that doesn't have recording, I would use some sort of screen capture software. Krita seems to have a capture interval, but I think personally, if possible I would record a video and then either pick and choose frames or just automatically drop out enough frames to make it look more like the example you gave.

Comment: @Joonas the problem with this is that it uses up a lot of resources and incluses all kinds of oops moments. But these kinds of things are very often requested, so its easier just to work in reverse as one gets a animation thats passable that way with less work.

Comment: @joojaa, you running PS on a pregnancy test or something? If my base model late 2012 macbook air can run PS and screen recording at the same time I would think most people should be able to...

Comment: @Joonas thats might be a problem if your doing 4k or 8k recording\*, but not really the main concern.  The problem is that you generate a lot of images that need to be curated and saved to disk. Then you need to reharsre the sketching so it goes well enough to be done etc. \* why generate anything less in 2022 than 4k?

Comment: @joojaa, while the video example from OP was clearly made by unmasking certain areas and revealing layers, like you suggested, which I would say looks ugly but that's irrelevant ...anyways, I'm not so sure I agree with the difficulties in using a recording. You can just trim away any sections where you tried something that didn't pan out. Or... if the framerate is low like in OP's example, all you have to do is pick and choose from the good frames in the video. Doesn't matter if you screwed up at any point in the video because you can just pick another frame. Would probably take like 5 minutes

Comment: @Joonas Erasing can also made better, its just a question of how much time and money your willing to give the animation team. The reverse is especially easy if you do enough sketchable layers. Im just pointing out that this is probably what would be done in video production. See the animator is rarely the same person who sketches the image so its easier form a production standpoint to work in reverse than teach the original author to work in way thats conductive for production. Also screw up is not necessarily noticed at recording time, its a huge risk. But ok if it pans out.